# Getting a different image resolution for Android camerax than specified with setTargetResolution()

Tags: android-camerax

I'm using camerax, and I'm using all 3 use cases:

- Preview - for the visual preview on the screen
- Image analysis - I'm running object detection
- Image capture - to get a high-resolution image after the object is detected

For both preview and image analysis I'm using `.setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)` which gives a default 640x480 image. I need to use 640x480 because the object detection model works well with that size.

I'm launching the image capture use case like this:

```
    imageCapturer = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(1600, 1200))
        .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
        .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
        .build()
```

This works fine on the virtual Pixel7 phone in Android Studio. **The problem** is that on my physical device (Nokia XR20), that always returns a 1944x1944 image, no matter what resolution I specify. Here's how it looks in Android Studio's debugger:

[image: screenshot of Android Studio debugger]

I cannot also call `.setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)` when building the image capture use case, because it throws an exception that you cannot use `setTargetAspectRatio` in conjunction with `setTargetResolution`.

I've already checked whether the resolutions I've tried requesting are valid for this camera with the following code:

```
        camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer, imageCapturer)
        val characteristics = CameraCharacteristicsCompat.toCameraCharacteristicsCompat(
            Camera2CameraInfo.extractCameraCharacteristics(camera!!.cameraInfo))
        val previewSizes = CamcorderProfileResolutionQuirk(characteristics).supportedResolutions
```

(That's camera2 code, but apparently it's a valid way to check for the camera's resolutions.)

`previewSizes` includes a couple of different 4:3 aspect ratio sizes I've tried:

```
...
16 = {Size@24268} "1600x1200"
...
20 = {Size@24272} "1280x960"
...
```

How can I reliably get a 4:3 aspect ratio size in a higher resolution for camerax?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the latest version, there is a new API called [ResolutionSelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/resolutionselector/ResolutionSelector), which gives you greater control on the resolution selection. Something like:

```
imageCapture.resolutionSelector = ResolutionSelector.Builder(ResolutionStrategy(Size(1600, 1200)))
```

The code is untested. However, please note that all the resolution selection APIs are "best effort". You cannot select a resolution the device does not support.